# CSS inheritance and overriding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap css and would like to override the `table` class only in selected screens.

I could do this:

```
.table th, td,
{
    border-top: 0;
}
```

and the border is removed as I had hoped to. However this is done for every single table.

I would like to specify which tables should have the border removed.

So if I did something like this:

```
<table class="edit_table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
```

How do I specify edit_table to inherit from `table` and remove the border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you could give it both `table` and `edit_table` classes:

```
<table class="table edit_table">
```

**Edit:** To be clear, I'd like to also mention that you can style `edit_table` however you want. The element will then apply styling from both `table` and `edit_table`.